# JavaScript (React): How to extend async function's await to a given time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I would like to have a async function that sends a request to a server and awaits the response. It will then wait upto 1000ms to ensure that an animation has played out.
i was wondering if I could combine these 2 tasks somehow so they add up to having waited 1000ms in total dynamically.

My current code:

```
const loadingHandler = async (func, target) => {
        setIsLoading(true);

        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
        await func(target);

        setIsLoading(false);
    };
```

**Some examples to further explain what exactly I mean:** the function calls `func()` and gets a response after (lets say) 200ms. Now the timeout is only supposed to be 800ms. If the `func()` returns after 20ms the timeout is supposed to be 980ms. If `func()` takes longer than 1000ms it should continue immedietly after getting the response and not wait additionally.
So is something like this 'stretcher await function' possible?

Comment: What if `func()` takes 2500ms? Should `loadingHandler` wait for that long or only be capped to 1000ms?

Comment: @VLAZ if it takes longer than 1000ms it shouldnt wait additionaly and continue immediately after getting the response. Also: no cap on the waiting time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just remember how long it's been so far, then delay that much longer:

```
const loadingHandler = async (func, target) => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    const started = Date.now();
    await func(target);
    const elapsed = Date.now() - started;
    const delayFurther = 1000 - elapsed;
    if (delayFurther > 0) {
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, delayFurther));
    }

    setIsLoading(false);
};
```

That said, holding up the user because an animation hasn't finished might not be the best UX. Perhaps you could make the animation finish more quickly when `func` is already done. (Humans tend to notice delays > about 80-100ms, a bit less when we're younger.)

Comment: Thank you, I'm still quite new to JS and this is exactly what I was looking for :D

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to Mr Crowder's perfectly valid solution: Rather than wait for the promise to finish and then checking if we need to start a new one, start two promises at the same time and wait for them both. Has the same effect, but makes the code shorter:

```
const loadingHandler = async (func, target) => {
  setIsLoading(true);
  await Promise.all([
    func(target),
    new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000)),
  ]);
  setIsLoading(false);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is a good approach too.

Comment: But wont this code continue after the 1000ms timeout is finished no matter if the function has returned?

Comment: No, the promise created by Promise.all will only resolve once *both* of the inner promises are done.

Answer (score 2):

In your code you starts first promise (interval), waits for it to finish, then starts second (func) and wait to finish. You should start both promises and wait for it together.

```js
const loadingHandler = async (func, target) => {
        setIsLoading(true);

        const p1 = new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
        const p2 = func(target);
    
        await Promise.all([p1,p2]);

        setIsLoading(false);
    };
```